# Node.js : How to use token with multer?

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I want to run two same servers. And I want to upload a image from one to the other. These sources worked well but I felt that verifying a token is needed for security.

I will use the function `createUploadToOther` of settings.js to send image to the other server. I usually write a router like
`router.post('/fromOther', verifyToken, function (req, res) {`

But in this case, I don't know where to put that verifyToken. Could u let me know how to use a token with the multer header(?) in this case?

**file.js**

```
let express = require("express");
let router = express.Router();


let path = require('path');
let uploadDir = 'static' 
let fs = require('fs');
const verifyToken = require('../libs/verifyToken')

const axios = require('axios')
const FormData = require('form-data')

let multer = require('multer');

let storageForSentFile = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) { 
    callback(null, uploadDir);
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {  
    callback(null, file.originalname);
  }
})
let uploadForSentFile = multer({ storage: storageForSentFile })



router.post('/fromOther', uploadForSentFile.single('logo'), function (req, res) {
  
  console.log("------file upload -------")
  console.log(req.file)
  res.json(req.file)

});

router.post('/toOther', uploadForSentFile.single('logo') , async function (req, res) {
  let formData = new FormData()

  formData.append('logo', fs.createReadStream(req.file.path), { knownLength: req.file.size })
  
  const headers = {
      ...formData.getHeaders(),
      "Content-Length": formData.getLengthSync()
  };
  
  try {
    let result = await axios.post(
      new URL('/file/fromOther', req.body.serverURL).href,
      formData,
      {headers }
    )
    
    res.status(200).json(result.data)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('file/toOther err', err)
  }
})
```

**../libs/verifyToken.js**

```
let jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
  console.log("req.headers1 : ", req.headers);
  let token = req.headers["authorization"];

  if (!token)
    return res.json({ status: 409, message: 'No authorization' })


  jwt.verify(token, process.env.aSecretKey, function (err, decoded) {
    if (err)
      return res
        .status(500)
        .send({ auth: false, message: "Check your ID and password" });
    console.log("decoded", decoded);
    req.account = decoded.account;
    req.idx = decoded.idx;
    next();
  });
}

module.exports = verifyToken;
```

**settings.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { headers } from '../config/env'

export function createUploadToOther(data) {
  return axios.post('/file/toOther', data, { headers })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function verifyToken in router(`'/fromOther'`) checks just `req.headers["authorization"]`, so I just added the function verifyToken to both router as argument(in fact don't need to add verifyToken to router(`'/toOther'`) but wanted to make it safer) and added the key `"authorization"` and the value as `req.headers.authorization` to router(`'/toOther'`). Then it worked well, but I don't know this will be safe enough.

```
//(...)
router.post('/fromOther', verifyToken, uploadForSentFile.single('logo'), function (req, res) {
  
  console.log("------file upload -------")
  console.log(req.file)
  res.json(req.file)

});

router.post('/toOther', verifyToken, uploadForSentFile.single('logo') , async function (req, res) {
  let formData = new FormData()

  formData.append('logo', fs.createReadStream(req.file.path), { knownLength: req.file.size })
  
  const headers = {
      ...formData.getHeaders(),
      "Content-Length": formData.getLengthSync(),
      "authorization": req.headers.authorization
  };
  
  try {
    let result = await axios.post(
      new URL('/file/fromOther', req.body.serverURL).href,
      formData,
      {headers }
    )
    
    res.status(200).json(result.data)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('file/toOther err', err)
  }
})
//(...)
```